# Is the yotube api v3 for java is a groovy only project?

Tags: java, swing, youtube-data-api

I was going through the google's **YouTube player demo** on [google's developer's site](http://developers.google.com) and it said it required **groovy 2.3** or higher. So just wanted to ask is it **compulsory to use Groovy** for making any project using this API ?

Answer (score 0):

> So just wanted to ask is it compulsory to use Groovy for making any
>   project using this API ?

**Answer: No.**
Google provide youtube-v3 libraries for almost all popular language. So that means you are not dependent on only groovy.

Have a look on this page:

1. [Sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java)
2. [YouTube Data API Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)
3. [github api-samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples)